# Update Symfony before Drupal core?

Tags: 8, updating

Right now there are some security updates for Symfony:

```
curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
echo y | ~/.symfony/bin/symfony self:update
~/.symfony/bin/symfony security:check
```

```
Symfony Security Check Report
=============================

2 packages have known vulnerabilities.

symfony/cache (v4.1.6)
----------------------

 * [CVE-2019-10912][]: Prevent destructors with side-effects from being unserialized

symfony/phpunit-bridge (v3.4.22)
--------------------------------

 * [CVE-2019-10912][]: Prevent destructors with side-effects from being unserialized

[CVE-2019-10912]: https://symfony.com/cve-2019-10912
[CVE-2019-10912]: https://symfony.com/cve-2019-10912

Note that this checker can only detect vulnerabilities that are referenced in the security advisories database.
Execute this command regularly to check the newly discovered vulnerabilities.
```

These can be easily updated:

```
composer update symfony/cache symfony/phpunit-bridge --with-dependencies
```

The question is, should we do these dependency updates ourselves or wait for the next Drupal core release that includes them?

For example, I'm thinking about a scenario where we would update a Symfony package that is a Drupal core dependency and something would go wrong with the update because the updated dependency hasn't been fully tested with Drupal.

Comment: Those packages are no dependencies of Drupal. If Symfony releases a security update for a package used by Drupal, Drupal will publish a new patch version including those security fixes.

Comment: @Hudri Thanks. On the specifics, you're right `symfony/cache` isn't a Drupal dependency. `symfony/phpunit-bridge` is a dependency of `webflo/drupal-core-require-dev`, which is for using BLT and updated along with `drupal/core`.

Comment: @Hudri In general (for dependencies of Drupal), do you recommend waiting for the Drupal core release that patches, and not doing it before that?

Comment: So far I've always relied on Drupal itself for updates, it was more than just fast enough for me with security fixes. `webflo/drupal-core...` is always tied 1:1 to a `drupal/core` patch release and is for dev environments only.

Comment: I've to admin I don't know how to handle version dispartities between `webflo/drupal-core...` or `drupal-composer/...` and `drupal/core` though

Comment: webflo uses `symfony/phpunit-bridge: ^3.4.3` which means it will be updated when using the recommended update command `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev "symfony/*" --with-dependencies` (this is from [drupal composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project))